# How many keyChain can I store in iOS?

Tags: ios, keychain, keychainitemwrapper

I'm using keychainWrapper. The keychain in ios stored using a pre-defined constant, which are these:

```
kSecAttrAccessGroup
kSecAttrCreationDate
kSecAttrModificationDate
kSecAttrDescription
kSecAttrComment
kSecAttrCreator
kSecAttrType
kSecAttrLabel
kSecAttrIsInvisible
kSecAttrIsNegative
kSecAttrAccount
kSecAttrService
kSecAttrGeneric
```

Does that mean I have restricted number of keychain I can use? I once used a custom key, and it doesn't work:

```
KeychainItemWrapper *keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] accessGroup:nil];
[keychain setObject:[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString] forKey:@"myUDID"];
```

But this does:

```
[keychain setObject:[[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString] forKey:(__bridge NSString *)kSecValueData];
```

So, is there anyway for me to save many keychain? Can I to init my keychain with a different identifier to get save more keychain? Like this:

```
anotherKeychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"TestUDID" accessGroup:nil];
[anotherKeychain setObject:udid forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
```

[How to store a string in KeyChain , iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459879/how-to-store-a-string-in-keychain-ios)

Comment: You can have any number of keychain items (what you are referring to as key chains are actually keychain items). Each item only has a limited number of attributes defined - you have listed these. The identifier is whatever you like and the data is the value you want to store against that item

Comment: There are also a number of frameworks you can use to simplify things - https://cocoapods.org/?q=KeychAin

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks Paul for pointing that out. Just confirm it, you're saying that I can have as many keychainsItem as I want, as long their identifier in the init method be different, right?

Comment: @Paulw11 You're right. I've just tested it, and it works! You should've post it as your answer so I can accept it :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have any number of keychain items (what you are referring to as key chains are actually keychain items). Each item only has a limited number of attributes defined - you have listed these. The identifier is whatever string you like and the data is the value you want to store against that item.

There are also a number of frameworks you can use to simplify things - http://cocoapods.org/?q=Keychain